# Rendering array items after making changes to its properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, rendering

I'm having an issue re-rendering items in an array after changes are made to elements in the array. Whether I add by pushing or remove by splicing, when the array is rendered again on the page, it like more items are being added to the array. So if I push onto the array, the item is added, but the old items are then duplicated into the array. Something similar happens when I remove items. The item looks to be removed, but the elements that were in the array show on the page, they are then duplicated and the item that was spliced is gone.

I'm trying to avoid a location.reload('/edit.html') to refresh the page. Kind of cheating. It seems to work, but I'm trying to get the page to refresh with my `renderIngredients` function. The `toggleIngredient` function is also duplicating the list of items when I check an item.

```
import { initializeEditPage, generateLastEdited } from './views'
import { updateRecipe, removeRecipe, saveRecipes, getRecipes, createIngredient } from './recipes'

const titleElement = document.querySelector('#recipe-title')
const bodyElement = document.querySelector('#recipe-body')
const removeElement = document.querySelector('#remove-recipe')
const addElement = document.querySelector('#add-recipe')
const dateElement = document.querySelector('#last-updated')
const addIngredient = document.querySelector('#new-ingredient')
const recipeStatus = document.querySelector('#recipe-status')

const recipeId = location.hash.substring(1)
const recipeOnPage = getRecipes().find((item) => item.id === recipeId)

titleElement.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const recipe = updateRecipe(recipeId, {
        title: e.target.value
    })
    dateElement.textContent = generateLastEdited(recipe.updatedAt)
})

bodyElement.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const recipe = updateRecipe(recipeId, {
        body: e.target.value
    })
    dateElement.textContent = generateLastEdited(recipe.updatedAt)
})

addElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    saveRecipes()
    location.assign('/index.html')
})

removeElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeRecipe(recipeId)
    location.assign('/index.html')
})

addIngredient.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    const text = e.target.elements.text.value.trim()
    e.preventDefault()

    if (text.length > 0) {
        createIngredient(recipeId, text)
        e.target.elements.text.value = ''
    }
    renderIngredients(recipeId)
    saveRecipes()
    //location.reload('/edit.html')
})

const removeIngredient = (text) => {
    const ingredientIndex = recipeOnPage.ingredients.findIndex((ingredient)=> ingredient.text === text)
    if (ingredientIndex > -1) {
        recipeOnPage.ingredients.splice(ingredientIndex, 1)
    }
    saveRecipes()
    renderIngredients(recipeId)
    //location.reload('/edit.html')
}

const toggleIngredient = (text) => {
    const ingredient = recipeOnPage.ingredients.find((ingredient) => ingredient.text === text)
    if (ingredient.included) {
        ingredient.included = false
    } else {
        ingredient.included = true
    }
    //location.reload('/edit.html')
}

const ingredientSummary = (recipe) => {
    let message
    const allUnchecked = recipeOnPage.ingredients.every((ingredient) => ingredient.included === false)
    const allChecked = recipeOnPage.ingredients.every((ingredient) => ingredient.included === true)

    if (allUnchecked) {
        message = `none`
    } else if (allChecked) {
        message = `all`
    } else {
        message = `some`
    }
    return `You have ${message} ingredients for this recipe`
}

const generateIngredientDOM = (ingredient) => {
    const ingredientEl = document.createElement('label')
    const containerEl = document.createElement('div')
    const checkbox = document.createElement('input')
    const ingredientText = document.createElement('span')
    const removeButton = document.createElement('button')
    recipeStatus.textContent = ingredientSummary(recipeOnPage)

    // Setup ingredient container
    ingredientEl.classList.add('list-item')
    containerEl.classList.add('list-item__container')
    ingredientEl.appendChild(containerEl)

    // Setup ingredient checkbox
    checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')
    checkbox.checked = ingredient.included
    containerEl.appendChild(checkbox)
    // Create checkbox button in ingredient div
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', () => {
        toggleIngredient(ingredient.text)
        saveRecipes()
        renderIngredients(recipeId)
    })

    // Setup ingredient text
    ingredientText.textContent = ingredient.text
    containerEl.appendChild(ingredientText)

    // Setup the remove button
    removeButton.textContent = 'remove'
    removeButton.classList.add('button', 'button--text')
    ingredientEl.appendChild(removeButton)
    // Create remove button in ingredient div
    removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        removeIngredient(ingredient.text)
        saveRecipes()
        renderIngredients(recipeId)
    }) 

    return ingredientEl
}

const renderIngredients = (recipeId) => {
    // Grab the ingredient display from the DOM
    const ingredientList = document.querySelector('#ingredients-display')
    const recipe = getRecipes().find((item) => {
        return item.id === recipeId
    })

    // Iterate through the list of ingredients on the page and render all items from recipeDOM
    recipe.ingredients.forEach((ingredient) => {
        const recipeDOM = generateIngredientDOM(ingredient)
        ingredientList.appendChild(recipeDOM)
    })
}

renderIngredients(recipeId)
```

I believe the issue stems from my renderIngredients function but I can't figure out how to fix it. Again, when I refresh the page, the results I want display, but I want to avoid using `location.reload`. I'm expecting the `removeIngredient` function to remove the ingredient with a button click and the page refreshes with the `renderIngredients` function. Also expecting the `toggleIngredient` function to just display a checkbox next to the ingredient I checked off, but that's not what's happening. The Same thing is happening when I use the `addIngredient` function, the ingredient is being added, but the ingredient that was already on the page is being duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to clear the list before adding the elements again:

```
ingredientList.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Gosh, all this time and I just needed to add that to the beginning of the renderIngredients function. Thanks!